# Same code works on one project but not in other. Error is NullPointerException but I created the object before using it

Tags: java, file

I am working in a Parser. The problem relies in opening a directory to scan the files in it. In my first project, the code works fine. But when I try to run the exact same code in a frame project the code stops working.

It's awfully stringe since it worked last night, but now it stopped working once more.

```
// This is the one not working    

    File actual;

    actual = new File("‪C:\\Users\\kalio\\Pictures\\JavaDocs");
    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println(actual.getPath());
    System.out.println(actual.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("==============================");
    for( File f : actual.listFiles()){}

 // This is the working one

    File actual;

    actual = new File("C:\\Users\\kalio\\Pictures\\JavaDocs");
    System.out.println("==============================");
    System.out.println(actual.getPath());
    System.out.println(actual.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("==============================");
    for( File f : actual.listFiles()){}

 // this is the output of the not working one

 ==============================
 ‪C:\Users\kalio\Pictures\JavaDocs
 false
 ==============================
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at parser.frmMenu$Scan.<init>(frmMenu.java:273)
at parser.frmMenu.btnSearchActionPerformed(frmMenu.java:256)
at parser.frmMenu.access$000(frmMenu.java:19)



 // this is the result of the working one

==============================
C:\Users\kalio\Pictures\JavaDocs
true
==============================
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate, since the object is created. The issue is that in a code it recognizes it as a directory while in the other it doesn´t.

Answer (score 0):

The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`File.listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) says:

> Returns `null` if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory*.

Your print statement says the path is not a directory, so that is why you get `NullPointerException`.

---

Don't know what *"in a frame project"* means, but if it means that it is running as a different user, then that user doesn't have access to your *private* folder.

`‪C:\Users\kalio` is a private folder for user `kalio`, and other users don't have access.

If this is the problem you're having, move the data outside the `‪C:\Users` folder, so the data is in a folder accessible to both `kalio` and whatever user is running your "frame project".

Comment: What I meant was that in the working one I have my main in a class, while in the not working one I have my main in a Jframe. I run both projects from the same directory which is "C:\Users\kalio\OneDrive\Documentos\NetBeansProjects". I don´t think this is the issue since I moved it as you proposed:

Comment: ==============================
‪C:\Users\Public\Documents
false
==============================
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at parser.frmMenu$Scan.<init>(frmMenu.java:273)
 at parser.frmMenu.btnSearchActionPerformed(frmMenu.java:256)
 at parser.frmMenu.access$000(frmMenu.java:19)